# How can I put this button 'add to card' above the product image?

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

How can I put this button above the product image?

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: try to change from layout file

Comment: It is very pretty your drawing

Comment: :) there is just a sock)

Comment: are you using `rwd` theme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app/design/frontend/{yourtheme}/{themename}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

find :

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
    ...
```

Then place it in the top of your page or above the image block.